# when i run this program without ''static '' keyword .it runs fine,but with '''static'' keyword it shows error

Tags: java

```
class Ideone {      
   static final int iop;//here static variable

    public Ideone()
    {
        iop=56;     
        System.out.println(iop);

    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      new Ideone();

    }
}
```

Here ERROR message

```
Main.java:14: error: cannot assign a value to final variable iop iop=56;
```

Comment: You have to show us what error messages you have received and put them in your question. Show what you have tried to do to fix the question.

Comment: Here ERROR message
Main.java:14: error: cannot assign a value to final variable iop
     iop=56;

Comment: nononononono. Put it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Static final variables should be used as constants and not initialized in the constructor.

Change it to

```
static final int iop = 56;
```

Answer (score 1):

`static final` variables cannot be initialized in the constructor.

You have three options to do so instead:

- Initialize **inline**:

  ```
  static final int iop = 56;
  ```
- Intialize through a **static method**:

  ```
  static final int iop = init();
  static int init() { 
      return 56; 
  }
  ```
- Intialize through a **static block**:

  ```
  static final int iop;
  static { 
      iop = 56; 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`static` - The variable can be used without an instance - like `Ideone.iop`.

`final` - The value of the variable cannot be changed.

When you declare the variable as `static final`, the JVM expects the value of the variable to be initialized. Otherwise the variable is of no use (It cannot be changed due to the `final`)

If you want it to be `static final, initialize it in the declaration and not the constructor.

`static final int iop = 56;`